# Updating layer extent after changing source in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I am running a python script in QGIS 3.8.3-Zanzibar where I am changing the source of a GeoJson file.

I am calling `layer.reload()` but subsequent calls to `layer.extent()` still return the old extent.  I can open the attribute table and zoom to the location and see the *selected* outline.

[image]

But the actual layer symbol does not display.

Things that I've tried:

1. I turned off canvas caching to rule that out.
2. I have tried these statements (in a variety of combinations):

   `layer.reload()`
    `layer.triggerRepaint()`
    `layer.setDataSource( layer.source(), layer.name(), layer.providerType() )`

I figure I'm missing something easy.

Comment: Try updating the extent using `layer.updateExtents()`

Comment: yep...that's it. I was scanning the wrong layer type in the docs, but  it's there in plain English! https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Vector/QgsVectorLayer.html?highlight=updateextents#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.updateExtents   @Joseph: make an answer, i'll vote/accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To update the extents of a layer after making any changes to its data source, use the [`QgsVectorLayer::updateExtents()`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a7e3a65d703c254a1b61c26335be30543) method:

```
layer.updateExtents()
```

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
if iface.mapCanvas().isCachingEnabled():
    lyr.triggerRepaint()
else:
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```